# Show that the the half open interval [a,b) is equal to the intersection of open intervals

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am having a little trouble understanding how to create such a sequence of intervals.

for example the open set (a,b) can be written as the intersection of the sets (a-1/n, b-1/n)

Comment: Where did you see this question?

Comment: The intersection of the intervals $(a-\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n})$ is *not* the interval $(a,b)$. The **union** of those intervals is the interval $(a,b)$, though...

Comment: What about $\bigcap_{n>0}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$?

Comment: The above comment answers the question. One could add that there are two errors in your post: in fact the closed interval $[a,b]$ is the intersection of the open intervals $(a-1/n,b+1/n)$.